# Play audio from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have a label, where i have the name of the audio,

```
<asp:Label ID="lblSound" runat="server" Text="sound.mp3"></asp:Label>
```

I implemented a HTML5 audio player into my aps .net web page with the following code:

```
 <audio controls>
  <source src="Sound/"></audio>
```

is it possible to get the text from the label and insert it in "source src="Sound/HERE"?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does the label look like? `<label>HERE</label>`?

Comment: @DaveChen, i get the text from the database; <asp:Label ID="lblSound" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem like this: `<audio controls> <source src="Sound/<%=FilePath %>" /></audio>`

I declared a global string: `protected string FilePath = "";`

and on the page load: `FilePath = lblSound.Text;`